# Enabling CSS modules in ReactJS by adding a .module to CSS file name

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS , I was reading about how to enable CSS modules and what i came to is:

> If you add .module it will add a base64 hash string to the name of classes used

Actually i created a function-based component `Layout.js`

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "./Layout.module.css";

const layout = props => <div className={classes.bg}>Here first div</div>

export default layout;
```

and css file as `Layout.module.css`

```
.bg {
  display: inline;
  background-color: rgba(115, 251, 4, 0.685);
}
```

When i inspected the `div` in browser:

```
<div class="Layout_bg__1bzIA">Here first div</div>
```

everything seems to work fine, But when i created another component `second.js` with a div in it and applied the same class

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "../Layout/Layout.module.css";

const second = props => <div className={classes.bg}>Here second div</div>

export default second;
```

And when i inspected the second div it looks like:

```
<div class="Layout_bg__1bzIA">Here seond div</div>
```

They both took the same hash value, So my question is it right what i quoted above

> .module enables CSS modules

And if it is , Why it gives the same hash values to different elements in different components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding module allows you to create same classes name without mixing them together. I mean by it that when you create another module with the same class name (in your case bg) it will have assigned different hash value which means they will have different names and therefore those two classes will never mix together. 
Hope that helps.